# replacing the special characters in a string in Ansible or Appending \ to special characters in the given string in Ansible

Tags: ansible

In my ansible playbook, I need to get a string an input from the user which may have special characters such as double quotes ("), paranthesis. I would like to add \ (slash) before every such special character.

For Example,

"(msg.commandCode=303 or msg.commandCode=302 or msg.commandCode=301) and msg.dest-host avpExists"

is to be changed to

\"\(msg.commandCode=303 or msg.commandCode=302 or msg.commandCode=301\) and msg.dest-host avpExists\"

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Need formatting

Answer (score 1):

The [`|regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) is designed for that purpose

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: the new string is {{ the_string | regex_replace(re1, re2) }}
  vars:
    the_string: '"(msg.commandCode=303 or msg.commandCode=302 or msg.commandCode=301) and msg.dest-host avpExists"'
    re1: '(["()])'
    re2: '\\\1'
```

where `\\` is the literal backslash character, and `\1` is the reference to the first capture group (of which there is only one)

I find using `vars:` and single quoted strings easier than fighting with yaml and backslashes, but it would work fine inlined into the jinja2 pipeline, also, if you manage to find the correct amount of *additional* backslashes to use